# No problems when there should be on Apple iOS Development Guide

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've started today to start learn development for iOS using [Apple's Official Guide for Swift Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html).

I've reached to [Work with View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html). A bit before the end of the page there is a checkpoint, where I should run the app on the simulator and when I click the Image View, I supposed to get `SIGABRT` error because I don't have permissions to show images.

Not only that I don't get any error messages, nothing happens at all when I click the Image View.

I've checked 3 times all over the files to make sure I didn't missed anything. I even created a new project to make sure everything was fine, but still, it doesn't work.

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

//MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Handle the text field's user input through delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self
}

//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
}

//MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
}
}
```

Main.storyboard:
[image: Main.storyboard]

Can you please help me solve it?

Comment: Might be your tap gesture is not connected from your story board to your file. Check the circle shown on the left of @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)  has grey filled inside. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu I checked it. It shows it is connected to the Tap Gesture Recognizer.

Comment: Then might be user interaction of your ImageView or the viewController's view is off.

Answer (score 0):

This error should occur when you are trying to access the camera roll without permission to do so.

iOS 10 requires that you add a description as to why you want access to the camera roll. This needs to be added in the info.plist file with the key `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`

If you are not getting this error, I would guess that you have already entered this information in the plist file our are running on an older version of iOS? or the code to access the camera roll is not actually firing, you may need to tap on screen or press a button to initiate the code.

Comment: I didn't enter yet the permission. Nothing happens although I don't have the permission and I don't get any errors on Xcode. I'm running the simulator on iOS 10.3. The code supposed to do that. I followed the guide one-by-one.

Comment: do you have a button to access the photos library? when you press it what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Tap Gesture Recognizer that I placed on a UIImage using Storyboard.

To get this to work I also had to place a checkmark in the block labeled: "User Interaction Enabled" in the UIImage's Attributes Inspector in the Storyboard.